# Why did Role assignment creation failed?

Tags: azure

I tried

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name “fabianomota” --sdk-auth --role contributor --scopes /subscriptions/a79aa2a0-00df-4174-950b-aaac4e10f48f/pichanagm
Option '--sdk-auth' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
Creating 'contributor' role assignment under scope '/subscriptions/a79aa2a9-00df-4174-950b-bbac4e10f48f/pichanagm'
  Role assignment creation failed.
```

I changed role

```
--role reader
```

again

```
Role assignment creation failed.
```

why did role assiment creation failed?
How to solve this?

Comment: Command doesn't seem to be correct. What is `pichanagm` in the scope?

Comment: Also, pay attention to the warning: `Option '--sdk-auth' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release.`

Comment: @VladDX Resource group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially I got the **same error**, when I tried the same command as you:

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name “rukk” --sdk-auth --role contributor --scopes /subscriptions/SubcriptionID/ruk
```

[image]

The error ***"Role assignment creation failed."*** usually occurs if you are passing invalid values or parameters to create the service principal and rbac for sp. Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/azure-cli-sp-tutorial-1?tabs=bash#create-a-service-principal-with-role-and-scope) for passing valid scope.

> **Note** that: **`--sdk-auth`** has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release.

**To resolve the error**, make sure to pass valid **scope** `/subscriptions/SubID/resourceGroups/ruk`

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name “rukk” --sdk-auth --role contributor --scopes /subscriptions/SubID/resourceGroups/ruk
```

[image]

Service Principal got created:

[image]

**Contributor role assigned to the Service Principal:**

[image]

Make use of **`az login`** to sign in and perform the action as `--sdk-auth` option will be removed in future release.

**Reference:**

[az ad sp | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-sp-create-for-rbac-optional-parameters)